# How to properly drain / release response body from WebFlux Client?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am using WebFlux HTTP Client from Spring 5 reactive stack to access external REST service. I want to process responses based on HTTP status:

1. If status is 2xx I want to return `Mono` with deserizlized response body.
2. If status is 404 I want to drop response body and immediately return empty `Mono`.
3. For any other status I want to drop response body and return error Mono with `MyBusinessException`.

My code looks like this:

```
webClient.get()
    .uri("/search")
    .syncBody(request)
    .exchange()
    .flatMap { response ->
        when {
            response.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful -> response.bodyToMono(MyResponse::class.java)
            response.statusCode() == NOT_FOUND -> Mono.empty()
            else -> MyBusinessException().toMono<MyResponse>()
        }
     }
```

I don't want to waste time to receive and process response body when I don't need it. JavaDoc for `exchange()` method states

> You must always use one of the body or entity methods of the response to ensure resources are released.

How exactly should I do this if I want to drain response body and return result immediately?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Draining the response is needed so that the connection can be reused for future requests (i.e. http keep-alive / persistent connections).

To return an empty `Mono` that completes after the body is drained (ignoring errors):

```java
// Using WebFlux >= 5.2
response.releaseBody()
    // ignore errors
    .onErrorResume(exception -> Mono.empty());


// Using WebFlux < 5.2
response.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers())
    // release DataBuffers
    .doOnNext(DataBufferUtils::release)
    // ignore errors
    .onErrorResume(exception -> Mono.empty())
    // return an empty Mono
    .then();
```

To return an empty `Mono` that completes immediately, and drain the body (ignoring errors) asynchronously in the background:

```java
// Using WebFlux >= 5.2
Mono.<Void>empty()
    .doOnSubscribe(s ->
        // drain the body
        response.releaseBody()
            // initiate drain on a separate Scheduler
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            // subscribe, and ignore errors
            .subscribe())

// Using WebFlux < 5.2
Mono.<Void>empty()
    .doOnSubscribe(s ->
        // drain the body
        response.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers())
            // release DataBuffers
            .doOnNext(DataBufferUtils::release)
            // initiate drain on a separate Scheduler
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            // subscribe, and ignore errors
            .subscribe())
```

I'd still recommend the first option, since it frees up resources immediately, and is probably what the `WebClient` developers had in mind when writing it and documenting its usage.

I've never used the second option in a production system, so do your own testing to ensure the http connection pooling is behaving as desired.  If using reactor-netty, you can enable debug logging on `reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider` to compare the two approaches.

Comment: Thanks. This `Mono` will complete after whole response is received. How can I return empty `Mono` that completes immediately while consuming response in the background? This is more of Reactor question but I am new to the theme and afraid to make mistakes like blocking the event loop, not properly subscribing etc

Comment: Answer edited to include example for draining in the background.

Comment: In the first option, if we need to return an empty publisher by default, do I need to do `response.releaseBody().onErrorResume(exception -> Mono.empty()).empty()`?

Comment: No, the publisher returned by `releaseBody()` is already empty, therefore the publisher returned by `onErrorResume` will also already be empty.